# Scala XML, delete node by pattern matching

Tags: xml, scala, pattern-matching

Hi i have a big xml file where i want to delete certain node, using pattern matching. A part of the xml looks like this:

```
<ddm:relation scheme="STREAMING_SURROGATE_RELATION">/path/to/somewhere/$id</ddm:relation>here
<ddm:relation randomattribute="que">something</ddm:relation>
<ddm:relation href="http:localhost:8080">que?</ddm:relation>
```

The only node i want to delete is the top one. Im using a [RuleTransformer](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/xml/transform/RuleTransformer.html) to do so. Within the transformer i use the following pattern matching:

```
override def transform(node: Node): Seq[Node] = node match {
  case Elem(_, "relation", _, _, _ @ _*)    => NodeSeq.Empty
  case n => n
}
```

But this does not differentiate between the relation nodes. How can i only remove the node that has the attribute `scheme`? Or a node containing a certain text, with pattern matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
  override def transform(node: Node): Seq[Node] = node match {
  case Elem(_, "relation", attr: MetaData, _, _ @ _*) if attr.prefixedKey == "scheme" => NodeSeq.Empty
  case n => n
}
```

Is there a more clean way though?